# How to Create a Smart Group before Anyone Belongs to it?

Tags: smartgroups

The usual way to create a Smart Group is :

1. Select (via Advanced Search) the contacts who meet the Search Criteria
2. Create the pertaining Smart Group

But is it possible to create a Smart Group before anyone meets the search criteria (so that the Group is automatically filled as soon as one contact meets the criteria) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create smart group from UI you need to have at least one result but from code its possible to do so.

From UI i would create a test contact so that it matches the smart group criteria. Then Find contacts >> create smart group, Delete the test contact permanently.

Cheers

Pradeep

Comment: Yes, I used to do so, but wanted to know if there is an other solution.

Comment: I do not know if there is a good reason why it can only be done with this workaround. If that's not the case, it would be a good feature request with the aim to simplify the pre-creation of smart groups.